# VBA Error 1004 - Application or Object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MergeCells()  

For i = 0 To 5996 Step 1
     ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Offset(i, 0).Resize(0, 18).Merge 
Next i  

End Sub
```

Thhis gives Error 1004 - I simply want to merge 18 cells across 5996 rows starting Row 4

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `.Resize(0, 18)`, the zero is not a valid option.

If you want to keep the existing number of rows while resizing, omit the argument:

```
.Resize(, 18)
```

Better yet, remove the loop and merge across in a single command:

```
Sub MergeCells()
    ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Resize(5997, 18).Merge True
End Sub
```